# Deleting rows in Pandas DataFrame based on values, from a specific range columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, slice

I feel like this question has been asked but I can't find an exact answer.

I have a large dataset with dozens of columns. I am trying to delete rows from the dataset when the value in any column is greater than 5, but I don't want to search the first two columns (those first two columns can have values greater than 5). I understand that specific columns can be named eg.( df.colname > 5), but how do I do it for a range of columns?

like this:

df = df[df.columns[2:34] > 5]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `.any` from `pandas` and the data frame from Brad

```
df[~(df.iloc[:,2:]>5).any(1)]
Out[403]: 
     a    b    c    d    e
0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: thanks for the response but this is just returning empty: 0 rows × 34 columns

Comment: @TajG  ***I am trying to delete rows from the dataset when the value in any column is greater than 5***

Comment: almost all of the values in the data are below 5. I am trying to delete the rows with values above 5. Your solution returns an empty set. It should only delete a few rows, not the entire set. Almost all of the data is below 5.

Comment: @TajG please check your 'real' data, without seeing it I can not provide the solution . I think there should be some column contain value more than 5

Comment: Okay I figured it out, the problem was that some column dtypes were 'object' instead of numeric, thanks for your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159094/discussion-between-taj-g-and-wen).

Comment: @TajG Sorry I can not using the chat .